# Probability - XOR of subset

Tags: probability, logic, boolean-algebra

There are 15 numbers (546,861,69,868,751,562,755,43,989,120,35,947,601,651,935) and you have to create a subset of those.
0.5,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.7 are the respective probabilities to include them in the subset.

Find the expected XOR of the subset.

I am using this algorithm to solve: https://discuss.codechef.com/t/expxor-editorial/25883 as I find both the questions very similar, but I am not getting the correct answer.

511.5 is what I got, but it's incorrect. **Edit: This turned out to be correct, the answer checker had a glitch.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What answer did you get?  Without doing any real calculation, I would guess something near $\frac{1023}{2}$ so if you are not near that in order of magnitude, you may have made a mistake

Comment: 511.5 is what I got, but it's incorrect. I'm unaware of the correct answer.

Comment: OK - So you are *very close* to my guess. I would not have expected my figure to be exactly right

Comment: And now I do expect my guess and your answer to be exactly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think each of the ten bits has a probability of about $0.5$ of surviving the XORs then the expectation should be about $\frac{2^{10}-1}2=511.5$

If you think each of the ten bits has a probability of exactly $0.5$ of surviving the XORs then the expectation should be exactly $\frac{2^{10}-1}2=511.5$

Four of the values have a probability of $0.5$ of going into the $XOR$ calculation.  Written in binary they are

```
546   1000100010
861   1101011101
562   1000110010
651   1010001011
```

and by observation each of the ten bits appears in at least one of these.

So we can conclude that $511.5$ is the correct answer.  To confirm, here is some R code which considers all the of the $2^{15}$ possibilities and their associated probabilities, confirming $511.5$

```
values <- c(546,861,69,868,751,562,755,43,989,120,35,947,601,651,935)
probs <- c(0.5,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.7)
combovalues <- 0
comboprobs <- 1

for (n in 1:length(values)){
  combovalues <- c(combovalues, bitwXor(combovalues, values[n]))
  comboprobs <- c(comboprobs * (1 - probs[n]), comboprobs * probs[n])
  }

sum(combovalues * comboprobs) 
# 511.5
```

Comment: The answer checker had a glitch, it's correct, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

this was a question in the code decode event of haywire dude. I am from mcs and this is cheating. Thanks for participating!

Comment: No this was not. https://discuss.codechef.com/t/expxor-editorial/25883. The question was copied from here as it is, and the solution was available online. I had solved it correctly hours before asking this, but my answer was still shown as incorrect because of a "site glitch".

Comment: Here is proof that I solved it before asking this here: http://pranavmittal.com/1.jpg